# What is the purpose of this eval conditional?

Tags: javascript, eval, conditional-statements, emscripten

I was browsing through the source code here: http://js-dos.com/games/doom2.exe.html and noticed a few things:

```
if (typeof Module === 'undefined') 
{
    Module = eval('(function() {try { return Module || {} } catch(e) { return {} }})()');
}
```

- The Module function is defined with an inline script tag
- It is later declared again with `var` in another inline tag, this time it checks if the Module exists.

**My question:** What is the point of declaring Module with a self invoking function if it'll only try to return the Module again? Hasn't it already been proven that it doesn't exist? Why not just explicitly declare Module as `{}`?

Comment: This code is on github in the emscripten project. It was added in this commit : https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/commit/22d510338239c1cf33136392c77a9b3d7d2ce2bc They've moved away from the explicit declaration to the eval statement, but the commit msg isn;t clear why! I've added emscripten as a tag, then someone from the project, or who knows it well, might spot it and be able to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typeof Module` might be undefined if Module is a local variable that happens to contain `undefined`. This code is meant to support a few cases, Module might be local or global, and defined or undefined. We want to avoid polluting the global scope, so we don't just do `Module = ...` if it's undefined.

First, the usual case is emscripten-generated code in the global scope. In this case, Module may or may not be defined, and may be local but still `undefined`, so we need to handle both.

Second, emscripten code may be just a module, like a game that uses ammo.js. In that case, the usage is

```
function Ammo(Module) {
  // emscripten-generated code, uses the Module
  return something;
}
```

so Module in this case is a function local, given as a param already defined for us.

We can't just declare `var Module` because that means Module is a local variable. So we need eval. For eval, we need a function that returns a value, because we need a try-catch. The try-catch uses Module, and will throw if Module is not a local (regardless of whether it contains `undefined` or not), which is exactly what we want.

It's possible this code could be simplified, though!

Comment: Since you don't mention it, for the record: **Alon is the author of those lines.**

Comment: The combo of github and SO is mighty impressive, & useful, for being able to take a question like this and join it up to the commit and then the author, who can then answer the question.